# Remove Forgot Password Link Based on Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.9, template, email, email-templates

I am trying to figure out how I can stop certain customer groups from changing their password. I was able to easily remove the link from the dashboard page but I can't figure out how to replicate this idea for the Forgot Password link on the login page. I attempted to create a custom block for the Forgot Password email, but it is not working. This is what I have in the block phtml template:

```
<?php $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->getCustomerGroupId() ?>
  <?php if ($groupId != 4): ?>
    Show link
  <?php else :?>
    Don't show link
  <?php endif ?>
```

How can I get this to work so the customer group 4 doesn't receive an email with the option to change their password?

Answer (score 1):

Since users viewing the login page are not yet logged in there isn't any way for them to have a customer group. I don't think this approach can work for you.

I would try creating an observer that attaches to the controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_forgotpasswordpost event. There you should be able to access the posted email address and get the customer group.

Comment: This approach should also prevent you from having to make and maintain changes to a bunch of templates.